# Retrieving all messages from a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get all messages to and from a facebook page, including those in the "Done" folder.

Using

`graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/conversations?fields=id,messages{message,to,from,created_time}`

I'm able to retrieve all messages in the inbox, but threads I've marked as "Done" in the web UI are not listed. I can retrieve their messages via

`graph.facebook.com/{conversation-id}?fields=id,messages{message,to,from,created_time}`

but that requires knowing the `conversation-id`.

I also know about the `conversations` webhook. While that's great for realtime and will work for all future messages, it doesn't help with retrieving historical messages, which I also want.

Is there a way to also get the `conversation-id`s for messages in the "Done" folder of a pages inbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can use `{page-id}/conversations?folder=page_done` with Page Access Token. It retrieves all threads in Done folder of Page inbox.